# Save vector elements in separate pdf files R

Tags: r

I have a vector which elements are pieces of text:
`foo <- c ("blah", "blah1", "blah2")`.
I need to save each element of the foo in a separate pdf document (in this case there will be three pdfs).

I tried `pdf()`, but did not work as the pdf file was empty. Can someone help solve this? Thanks.

Comment: pdf is a *graphics* device. You can use plot.new and text but if you want actual text in the pdf you should look into knitr.

Comment: I have never used it. Tried it now and was able to produce one pdf using RStudio knit (used the default example). I had to press the knit button. Is it possible to do this automatically for all elements of my vector? For pdf() I was thinking to use sapply or something like that, but no idea how can I do it in RStudio markdown. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop and knit2pdf from knitr package:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
knit2pdf(df$col[i])
}
```

See ?knit2pdf

Comment: Accepted the answer as at least it offers me a guide. Thanks. However I tried the code and it did not work (con is not a connection). I will read the documentation.